# css menu bar issue in hover state in html5

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

This is my css:

```
.nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.nav li {
    display: table-cell;
}
.nav li a {
    background: #FF0000;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
.nav ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;

}
.nav li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
.nav ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
.nav ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #069;
}
```

**JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/spog4sqg/3/

Here when hover over `HOME` display `text-decoration:underline;`, when hover over other remaining list, display like this: http://s7.postimg.org/br5nkl8zf/Untitled_1_copy.png

May i know, what is the exact css property to fix this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: no `text-decoration: underline;` when hover over `HOME` in your fiddle link, what is the problem, and what did you expect

Comment: @Kyojimaru: Did you see my posted image?

Comment: yes, but I don't really understand what's the problem as there's no `underline` either in fiddle or your posted image and what did you expect or want it should be

Comment: you want to have `underline` effect on hover only for home, company, markets, ... until investers, or for every nested `li` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, that instead of the underline property, you mean that you want the hover state to stay active when you hover the child list.

In order to do so, trigger the hover effect on the list-item instead of the anchor.

Change:

```
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#000;
}
```

To:

```
.nav li:hover a {
    background-color:#000;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/spog4sqg/6/).

**[EDIT]**

Hope I understand your comment right. By 'underline' you mean that the submenu gets a background-color?
Then change it to:

```
.nav li:hover ul li a {
    background-color:#000;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/spog4sqg/10/).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but HOME-> hover effect need only underline, but now shows, underline and background-color effect.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is what you're looking for:

```
.navigation > ul li:first-child a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[See Example](http://jsfiddle.net/spog4sqg/8/)

Answer (score 1):

I used :first-child pseudo-class, hope that helps?

```
.nav li:first-child a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w81swq5j/2/